# Add comma to textbox after spacing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a script that adds a comma and space (after the comma) to a textbox when a user presses the space bar.
If no text has been inserted then a comma should not be added. I have looked everywhere to find a solution.

**Example**

```
This, Is, A, Keyword
```

**Here is my current jQuery for this textbox**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#tags').keyup(function(){
      this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$('#tags').keyup(function(){
   var str = this.value.replace(/(\w)[\s,]+(\w?)/g, '$1, $2');
   if (str!=this.value) this.value = str; 
});
```

Contrary to the naive approach, it will also work if the user go on typing ands add other spaces.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ekeziq/5)

EDIT : I changed to test if the value changed, because I wanted to let the user navigate with arrows.

Comment: Is there anyway to add a class to the text between the commas? Like make them have a blue box around them or something like stack overflow does?

Comment: @ChristianRankin - Not with a textarea. However with a contentEditable, there are things you can do like insert a span with a required class.

Comment: Ahh okay I'll definitely check that out.

Comment: I was using this and was wondering, anyway to remove a comma if the user puts one by accedent before pressing space bar? Like `keyword,,` --> `keyword,(space)`